# How to fix aws lambda function logs error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to extract aws trust advisor data through lambda function(trigger by event scheduler) and upload to s3. However, some part of the function throws error. below is my code

```
##libraries
import boto3
import os
import csv
from csv import DictWriter
import time
import traceback

## bucket_name is set as env variable
bucket_name = "test-ta-reports"
fail_msg = 'Pulling Trusted Advisor data failed'
Filename = "/tmp/checks_list.csv"
obj_name = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S") + '/' + '.csv'

##upload to s3
def s3_upload(bucket_name, Filename, obj_name):
    
    if obj_name is None:
        obj_name = os.path.basename(Filename)
    try:
        s3 = boto3.client("s3", region_name="eu-west-1")
        response = s3.upload_file(Filename, bucket_name, obj_name)
        return True
    except:
        print('Data failed to upload to bucket')
        traceback.print_exc()
        return False
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        support_client = boto3.client('support', region_name='us-east-1')
        ta_checks = support_client.describe_trusted_advisor_checks(language='en')
        checks_list = {ctgs: [] for ctgs in list(set([checks['category'] for checks in ta_checks['checks']]))}
        
        for checks in ta_checks['checks']:
            print('Getting check:' + checks['name'] + checks['category'])
            try:
                check_summary = support_client.describe_trusted_advisor_check_summaries(
                                checkIds=[checks['id']])['summaries'][0]
                if check_summary['status'] != 'not_available':
                    checks_list[checks['category']].append(
                       [checks['name'], check_summary['status'],
                        str(check_summary['resourcesSummary']['resourcesProcessed']),
                        str(check_summary['resourcesSummary']['resourcesFlagged']),
                        str(check_summary['resourcesSummary']['resourcesSuppressed']),
                        str(check_summary['resourcesSummary']['resourcesIgnored'])
                        ])
                else:
                    print("unable to append checks")
                       
            except:
                print('Failed to get check: ' +  checks['name'])
                traceback.print_exc()
    except:
        print('Failed! Debug further.')
        traceback.print_exc()
    
    ##rewrite dict to csv
    with open('/tmp/checks_list.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        csv_writer = DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=['status','hasFlaggedResources','timestamp','resourcesSummary','categorySpecificSummary', 'checkId'])
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        csv_writer.writerow(check_summary)
        return checks_list
        
    if s3_upload(bucket_name, Filename, obj_name):
        print("Successfully uploaded")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lambda_handler(event, context)
```

The error logs

```
unable to append checks
```

I'm new to Python. So, unsure of how to check for trackback stacks under else: statement. Is there any way to modify this code for getting traceback logs for the append block. Also, have i made any error in the above code. I'm unable to figure out any. PLz help

Comment: Check CloudWatch logs for your function.

Comment: i did! The cloudwatch logs had only the error : '' unable to append checks". Also, the " print('Getting check:'  " statement is executed properly and i can see those logs as well.

Comment: my guess is that the error occurs between the second try statement and the else print append statement. i might be wrong though

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
response = client.describe_trusted_advisor_check_summaries(
    checkIds=[
        'string',
    ]
)
```

**describe_trusted_advisor_check_summaries()** returns summarized results for one or more Trusted advisors.  Here you are checking for the **check_summary['status']** is **not equal** to **not_avaialble** i.e. alert status of the check is either "**ok**" (green), "**warning**" (yellow), "**error**" (red), and in that case, you are appending resourcesProcessed, resourcesFlagged, resourcesSuppressed, and resourcesIgnored to checks_list for further processing.

it's printing

```
unable to append checks
```

just because the status of the check is **not_available**. It is not an error log. Just deal with the case if the check status is not_available, what you should be doing?

See the documentation of describe_trusted_advisor_check_summaries. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/support.html#Support.Client.describe_trusted_advisor_check_summaries